# What's the appropriate directory structure for a Gradle-based Android Project with Robolectric

Tags: android, intellij-idea, jenkins, robolectric

I'm new to the world of Android and is currently constructing the infrastructure of my first app. After some research, I've decided to build a Gradle-based Android Project with Robolectirc for unit testing.

I've created the project on IntelliJ IDEA using the wizard.. I selected Android > Gradle:Android Module. It generated two modules: one is the project base module, the other is the **code** (I named it) module.

Now I'm going to add tests for my FirstActivity. I look at some sample project - [deckard-gradle](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle), the test folder is under the same /src directory and parallel to the /src/main. I wonder if this is a common practice to have tests and code within the same module, or is it better to have a separate, corresponding testing module.

Note: I'm using Jenkins for continuous integration. What I want to achieve is to automatically run test cases and only make a build if all tests pass.